# Android - Facebook integration - get news feed / all statuses / facebook startpage

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently writing an App where I want to include various social media accounts in one Feed. Twitter worked great. Now I'm fighting with Facebook to achieve the same. But its not working :/ I'm using the Facebook-android-sdk and searched the Docs twice... (maybe i'm just blind)

**Problem:**
I want to get the news feed of Facebook. But not the users posts or timeline. In other words I don't want `/me/feed?fields=foo`.
So basically i want the startpage of facebook when you logged in. So this feed where I can see all status updates of my friends and pages i "liked"

Does someone Have some information or solutions for this? I can provide more information if something is not clear.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get access to the feed of friends, if they did not authorize your app with the `user_posts` permission. You can only get the feed of Pages you liked:

- Authorize with the `user_likes` permission
- Use the `/me/likes` endpoint to get the Pages
- Use the `/page-id/feed` endpoint to get the feed of the Pages

The API Reference includes example code for those API calls: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Comment: That sounds good! Thanks... i will test and check this! But when they authorize my app with the `user-post` permission than I can do this the same way as with the pages and than just merge the 2 lists... am I right or do I miss something here?

Comment: When you read a user’s feed, the posts of friends that have also granted your app access to their posts will be included automatically. This is explained under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/feed#read

Comment: @CBroe Yeah I noticed that myself :D ... but thats not so good actually, I need the complete list to reproduce this news feed with the `pages/feed`. But i think facebook don't want this :/

Comment: Exactly. First of all to protect user’s privacy. And that you should not build apps that "replicate core Facebook functionality" (and the feed is core functionality) is also part of Platform Policy.

Comment: @CBroe Ahh okay Thank you! But why is than Twitter offering it? :D nvm it's another topic... ;)